# Laravel 5.1 - One To Many with custom key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to create a one-to-many-relationship between two instances of the same class using Laravel 5, on the newest laravel-homestead built. However, for some reason laravel is not saving any relationships to persistence.

This is my eloquent-model class:

```
class Page extends Model
{

//relationship
public function subpages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Ordiweb\Page','motherpage','pagename');
}

public function motherpage()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Ordiweb\Page','motherpage','pagename');
}

//table-name
protected $table = 'pages';
protected $primaryKey = 'pagename';
protected $timestamps = false;

//fillable attributes
protected $fillable = ['pagename','pagetitle','pagecontent','boxcontent'];
}
```

So a page can be a motherpage of 0..n subpages. The motherpage and the subpages are all instances of the Page-class.

I'm not completely sure about the foreignKey ('motherpage') and localKey ('pagename') params at belongsTo() and hasMany() but the laravel documentation does not really explain how they are used. However, when I run my migrations I do not get any errors, so I guess it's done the correct way.

This is my correspondening migration-class:

```
class CreatePagesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('pagename');
        $table->string('motherpage')->nullable();
        $table->string('pagetitle')->nullable();
        $table->text('content')->nullable();
        $table->text('boxContent')->nullable();

        $table->primary('pagename');
        $table->foreign('motherpage')->references('pagename')->on('pages')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('pages');
}
}
```

Here's my pagetable seeder:

```
class PageTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    DB::table('pages')->delete();

    $page = new Page();
    $page->pagename = 'testpage';
    $page->pagetitle = 'Testpage Title';
    $page->content = '<h3>Hello</h3>';
    $page->save();

    $page2 = new Page();
    $page2->pagename = 'testpage2';
    $page2->pagetitle = 'Testpage2 Title';
    $page2->content = '<h3>Hello 2</h3>';
    $page2->boxcontent = 'Test in the box.';
    $page2->save();

    $page->subpages()->save($page2);
    $page2->motherpage()->associate($page);
    $page->save();
    $page2->save();

}
}
```

As you can see I trying to define the relationship via both ways.

1. Setting the hasMany via ->subpages()->save($page2);
2. Setting the reverse-hasMany via ->motherpage()->associate($page);

When running: "artisan migrate:refresh --seed" everything seems to work fine, no error messages appear. Except for the relationship-data all the defined models with properties are saved to persistence. Only the relationship fields stay null.

As you can see in the image the motherpage-field of "testpage2" should be "testpage" and not NULL

[image: Data in pages-table via HeidiSQL]

I really don't know what do from here on. Everything seems to be set up correctly, where did I mess up?

Comment: I think a page should belong to many subpages. Try this:

`public function subpages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Ordiweb\Page','motherpage','pagename');
}`

Comment: Hm? Whats the difference to my subpages()?

Comment: My bad. I meant to change hasMany to belongsToMany.

Comment: This also does not work. :( But I have to say, I would have been suprised since the laravel docs itself state to use belongsTo() for the inverse-one-to-many relationship.

see here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: After changing to belongsToMany try removing '$page2->save();' before calling ' $page->subpages()->save($page2);' in your Seeder.

Comment: OK. Got it fixed. I enabled the DB query log to look directly at the queries and something was odd. The at the updates to set the relationships the pagename always was "0". For some reason even if they were wrote correctly to database, the eloquent primaryKey was not set.

So above the 
    $page->subpages()->save($page2);
    $page2->motherpage()->associate($page);
lines I added:
    $page = Page::find('testpage');
    $page2 = Page::find('testpage2');

And now everything works right. The belongsTo()- and hasMany()-stuff was set up correctly.

Comment: The solution was the one i mentioned? If so I will post it as an answer so it will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: Nope, sorry. See my answer. :)

Comment: No prob. I saw it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

By looking at the database log I discovered that after the eloquent models were written correctly to the database (including the `pagename` primary key), for some reason the  `pagename` properties of the model instances in the seeder-class were set to '0'. By retrieving the model instances freshly from the DB **BEFORE** setting the relationships I got it fixed.

```
$page = Page::find('testpage');
$page2 = Page::find('testpage2');

$page->subpages()->save($page2);
$page2->motherpage()->associate($page);
$page2->save();
```